# How do I reduce the time for npm install across multiple TeamCity builds?

Tags: node.js, npm, teamcity

### Problem

- We have a large number of build configurations in TeamCity that deal with npm installs of many of the same packages
- Because we need to enforce clean checkouts for a lot of our builds (e.g. all PRs), the `node_modules` folder within a given build will never be re-used
- The npm install portion of our build takes 4 minutes, which is around 40% of the time for a given build.
- Across hundreds of builds a day on 10 agents, this is a number worth reducing.

### Question

What is the recommended way to centralize / re-use the `node_modules` folder between builds given our stack?

### Technology Stack

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Node LTS 4.x
- TeamCity 9.x

### What We've Tried

- **Use `npm cache`** -- This happens by default, so at least it's not like we're downloading packages from the internet every time.
- **Symlinking `node_modules` to a common directory** -- This approach worked (went from minutes to seconds) but unfortunately some gulp/grunt tasks fail when dealing with symlinks on Windows. Womp womp.

### Other Approaches We're Trying

- **Create a `node_modules` folder further up the hierarchy**: Not sure, but it seems like node may hierarchically search for the `node_modules` folder. In that case, creating a `node_modules` folder in a parent directory may solve the issue.
- **Use the `NODE_PATH` environment variable** -- Not sure if setting this will do something different similar to the point above and provide a common `node_modules` folder when one is not found in one of our builds.
- **Use Powershell to `Move-Item` back & forth between a backup directory**: If we have to hack it, it might be worth it to use a backup directory per project ID and use `Move-Item`, which should update partition links rather than copying files, at least. [That approach is outlined on this blog post](https://beerandserversdontmix.com/2016/06/04/teamcity-and-avoiding-redownloading-of-npm-packages/).

Comment: @seanKillen did you ever find a good solution for this? - we have the same problem on our jenkins builds

Comment: @pogorman not yet -- the best we've got now is trying `Move-Item`. I wanted to experiment with symlinks more now that we're dealing with webpack instead of gulp; I don't have access to the servers I was experimenting on previously though. Hoping to try that soon.

Answer (score 1):

What you have been doing is the best practice in the industry. I dont know if u can make it any better with npm.

have u tried yarn instead https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn
there is a way to use along with docker too
https://hackernoon.com/using-yarn-with-docker-c116ad289d56#.8bhk0tkz4

Answer (score 0):

I'm told you can turn off progress reporting and speed it up significantly:
http://biercoff.com/how-to-crazy-easily-speed-up-your-npm-install-speed/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried docker cache?

Put your `npm install` in Dockerfile, run `docker build`

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /code

RUN npm install # skiped when package.json/package-lock.json not changed.

ADD . /code

# do other things
```

Docker build creates a layer for each command(COPY/ADD/RUN), and use the layer as cache(if nothing changed) when build agagin.

As long as package.json/package-lock.json not changed

`docker build` will use cache for

`COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /code`

and

`RUN npm install`

so you don't need to speed up `npm install`, it just skiped.